# Datetime Difference Error

Tags: php, datetime, diff

I have a problem when I use difference of the datetime.

Here is the php code

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->days;
```

The correct result should be 2. But unfortunately it results `6015`. Even when I change the date, its still `6015`. Did you guys encounter this problem? I tried to run the script from other computer but its working.

Comment: Try setting timezone in DateTiem to 'UTC'

Comment: This says `2`: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wa4xVo So I imagine you have a setting out of whack or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$start_date = new DateTime("2009-10-11");
$end_date = new DateTime("2009-10-13");
$interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);
echo "Result " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ";
```

you use `$interval->days` replace with `$interval->d." days "`

you can check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14938421/718224 on date difference for more information.

may this help you.

Answer (score 2):

yes sure man for that you need to assign timezone

try this code
i set it for india

```
$MNTTZ = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata');
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11',$MNTTZ);
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13',$MNTTZ);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->days;
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to set format()

```
 <?php
    $datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
    $datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
    ?>
```

[see here...](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)