# The bug Fatal error: Cannot redeclare date_diff() in

Tags: php, datediff, redeclare

I used cakephp with version 1.1.7692.

When i run it with php ver > 5.3.2, it has bug :

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare date_diff().
```

and i run it with php ver 5.2.9, it display very text and code same as :

```
quality = 100; $thumb->fileName = "/path/to/file.jpg"; //IMPORTANT -
must run init() function before any manipulation is performed
$thumb->init(); //shrink image by 50% $thumb->percent = 50;
$thumb->resize(); //crop image to 350x350 from center of image
$thumb->cropSize = 350; $thumb->crop(); //resize image to no more than
125px wide $thumb->percent = 0; $thumb->maxWidth = 125;
$thumb->resize(); //save image as 'filename.jpg'
$thumb->save('/path/to/save/filename.jpg'); You can also use this
class to dynamically generate thumbnails and display them After you
have made your manipulations you could display the result by: echo '';
*/ class ThumbnailComponent extends Object { var $errmsg;    //error message to parse var $error;    //flag for whether there is an error var
$format;     //file format of image var $currentDimensions=array(); 
//current dimensions of working image var $newDimensions=array();   
//new dimensions after manipulation var $newImage;   //final image to
be displayed/saved var $oldImage;    //original image to be manipulated
var $workingImage;   //working image being manipulated var $fileName;   
//filename of image, can include directory var $maxWidth;    //maximum
width of the image var $maxHeight;   //maximum height of the image var
$percent;    //percentage of the original image size var $quality;  
//image quality of jpeg images var $cropSize;....
```

This is function  date_diff :

```
function date_diff($start_date,$end_date)
    {
        $splitstdate = split(" ",$start_date); 
        $splitenddate = split(" ",$end_date); 

        list($year,$month,$day)=split("-",$splitstdate[0]);
        list($year_test,$month_test,$day_test)=split("-",$splitenddate[0]);


        list($hour,$min,$sec)=split(":",$splitstdate[1]);
        list($hour_test,$min_test,$sec_test)=split(":",$splitenddate[1]);

        $start = mktime($hour, $min, $sec,$month,$day,$year);
        $end = mktime($hour_test, $min_test,$sec_test,$month_test,$day_test,$year_test);
        $date_diff =   $start-$end;
        if($date_diff<0)
        $date_diff=0;
        $days = intval($date_diff /(3600*24)) ; 

        $hms = date('h \h\r \m\i\n s \s\e\c \a\g\o',$date_diff);
        return $days.' days '.$hms ;
}
```

Who can know the cause of bug and method resolve it?
Thanks all.

Comment: You can't run anything with php ver. 6.2.9... it's not even released!

Comment: @DiegoAgulló 
i'm sorry. i'm confusion. it is 5.2.9

Comment: @Hyeongsik +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

`date_diff` is inbuilt function in `php` version `5.3.0` you can't redeclare it.

Comment: yes. it is inbuilt function in php. i dont edit anything but it has a bug.

Comment: If you want the code to be backwards-compatible, just use `function_exists` to avoid redeclaration if the function is natively implemented.

Comment: No its not a bug.It was added in php version 5.3.0. Because of that it gives error in 5.3.2 and not in 5.2.9.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, Are you mean it need has php ver 5.3.0 ?

Comment: @Hyeongsik Yes it requires version 5.3.0.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar i used ver php 5.3.0, but it still so.

Answer (score 3):

`date_diff()` is inbuilt function of php version 5.3.0. and above version, you can check http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php that's why you get `Fatal error: Cannot re-declare date_diff()` so change your function name this will solve your problem

you can check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14938421/718224 on date difference for more information.

**NOTE:** In versions < 5.3.0 I simply use this form for calculate the number of days

```
<?php
$today = strtotime("2011-02-03 00:00:00");
$myBirthDate = strtotime("1964-10-30 00:00:00");
printf("I'm %d days old.", round(abs($today-$myBirthDate)/60/60/24));
?>
```

Comment: I was change the function date_diff to a other name. but it still so.

Comment: @Hyeongsik date_diff() use above 5.3.0 and above version of php.

Comment: Thanks @Advait Amin, i was run  it ok with php version 5.0. But in now i cant enter in phpadmin, because it required php 5.2+.
pls help me?

Comment: @Hyeongsik, Why you not accepting answer??? Is my answer helpful to you or not???

Comment: I try the method of you. but  i cant resolve my problem .
so that i selected methos upgrade version cakephp 1.1 to 1.3.