# how to set timer in pagination php

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, pagination

I want to use time in pagination.In my script when click on next the timer restarts..i think session will help me.but i don't understand how to collect correct time in session and display that in another page in pagination.This is my javascript code:

```
var myTime = "20";

function countDown() {
    document.form.seconds.value = myTime;
    if (myTime == 0)
    {
        location.href="abc.php";
    }
    else if (myTime > 0)
    {
        myTime--;
        setTimeout("countDown()",2000);
    }
}
```

and this is how i set the time in my php file:

```
<form name="form">
    Time Left: <input type="text" name="seconds" size="3">
</form>
```

Comment: hoping somebody will help me...........

Answer (score 0):

Using session is really very simple. Just include: session_start(); at the beginning of every PHP file of your script.

Then, in order to set a time variable, use this: `$_SESSION['theTime'] = $currentDateTime;`

where `$currentDateTime = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());`

Now, this `$_SESSION['theTime']` variable will be passed on to every PHP file if you include `session_start();` at the beginning of each. To find out difference between two times, refer this: [php: datetime() difference between 2 datetime with 2 variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938339/php-datetime-difference-between-2-datetime-with-2-variables)